# How can I count the number of occurrences in a string based on character letter?

Tags: c++

My code is supposed to take user input of a file with a single string line and user input of the characters within that file and then count the number of occurrences of each character within that string. I have this code so far
[Working code to count only one of the characters in the string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/853Eg.png). [The two inputs & Output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybefK.png). [Text File contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74PUW.png). This code allows me to take the user inputs and count the number of occurrences of only one of the characters. My question is how would I be able to loop the count function to count as many times as there are user inputted characters?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Ask for user input of charcters in file & store in symbols
    char symbols [50];
    string file;
    cin >> symbols;

    //Read file name & contents then store in string called values
    cin >> file;
    ifstream document (file);
    string values;
    getline(document,values);
    //cout << values << "\n";
    
    //Search for and count letters in string and then put count in an array named occurances
    char searching = symbols[0];
    int counter = 0;
    int occurances [] = {};  
    for(int i=0;i<values.length();i++)
    {
        if(searching == values[i])
        {
            counter++;
        }

     occurances[0] = counter;
    }
    cout << "Symbol: " << symbols[0] << ", Frequency: "<< occurances[0] << ", Code:  " << " placeholder" << endl;
    
    
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a loop?

Comment: Stand on the shoulders of giants. Use [`std::count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count).

Comment: Your code is C++ not C. They are different languages and where it comes to your question, there's half a century of progress between them.

Comment: Why do you use character arrays when you are using `std::string`?

Comment: Also, read [ask] and please don't post images or links to images of code. Always post the formatted source or, when appropriate a link to the source.

Comment: @jwdonahue Disagree with the half century of progress. C has progressed into a better C just like C++ has progressed into a better C++. It's like saying humans are more evolved than monkeys. They aren't. The modern monkey is a way better monkey than the monkey-like thing humans and monkeys branched from. It sucks at being a human, but it's an amazing monkey. Meanwhile the human is a really crappy tree-dwelling brachiator, but can travel to the moon.

Comment: @user4581301, yes, but not so much in the area of the standard libraries. And your analogy falls apart when you consider that, say a Chimp AND a Human, are about a million years more evolved than whatever it was they evolved from.  Anyway, it's a C++ question, that could be using C++ standard libraries that didn't come along until about a half century after the C libraries were first laid down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would build a histogram (frequency) of the letters, then query the histogram:

```
// Assume ASCII encoding

int main()
{
  std::string filename;
  std::cout << "Enter filename: ";
  std::getline(std::cin, filename);
  std::ifstream data_file(filename);
  if (!data_file)
  {
    std::cerr << "Error opening " << filename << "\n";
    return 1;
  }

  // Use 256 entries for ASCII, just to simplify the code
  // although ASCII max value is 127.
  char frequencies[256] = {0};

  // Build histogram / frequencies.
  const unsigned int  BUFFER_CAPACITY = 1024u * 1024u;
  static char buffer[BUFFER_CAPACITY];
  std::cout << "Creating histogram ...\n";
  while (data_file.read(buffer, BUFFER_CAPACITY))
  {
      const std::size_t chars_read(data_file.gcount());
      for (unsigned int i = 0U; i < chars_read; ++i)
      {
          const char index = buffer[i];
          frequencies[index]++;
      }
  }
  // TBD by O.P.
  return 0;
}
```

The frequency of a given letter is:
`unsigned int freq = frequency[letter];`

To get the frequency of all the vowels, you could do something like this:

```
static const char vowels[] = "AEIOUaeiou";
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (sizeof(vowels) - 1U); ++i)
{
  std::cout << vowels[i] << ": " << frequencies[i] << "\n";
}
```